# White line in Eagle Editor: Board

Tags: eaglecad

This is what I see when I select and move an entire group in Eagle 9.6.0  .

**General Perspective:**
[image]

**On the other side:**
[image]

**Another example:**
[image]

What is the white line shooting out of the board's boundary?

Comment: Probably a connection to another part you haven't shown. Pan your view and see what's at the other end of the line.

Comment: nothin'.........

Comment: Please share a screen shot showing the other end of the line.

Comment: It's very hard to zoom in because it only appears when moving and the line is quite long

Comment: Perhaps it's a lebel?

Comment: Select all layers for viewing - it's likely a component that you have inadvertently placed on an unused layer.